# Django 2 - ORM - Annotate Substraction of two sums order is not mathematically respected

Tags: python, django

At the moment we are trying to order a list of videos based on their difference of up and down votes (=> points). The logic is simple:
Take a video, sum all Upvotes by each user and sum all Downvotes by each user. 
Substract the downvote sum from the upvote sum. 
Call the result points. 
Order the list by points descending.

An expected result would be:

```
Video A : 5 Upvotes : 4 Downvotes : 1 Point
Video B : 3 Upvotes : 3 Downvotes : 0 Points
Video C : 0 Upvotes : 0 Downvotes : 0 Points
Video D: 0 Upvotes : 1 Downvote : -1 Point
```

We have done this with the following Django 2 model queryset:

```
    from django.db.models import F, Sum
...
    q = Video.objects.filter(createdAt__year=year, is_active=True,
                                         is_public=True)
    videos = q.annotate(points=Sum("votes__up") - Sum("votes__down")).order_by("-points")[:15]
```

Unfortunately though, the "ordered" list looks as followed:
[image: returned list]

As we can see from the returned ordered list, it does not respect that -1 is less than 0 and should come after any result that has 0 points.

Is there something wrong with our querymodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
videos = q.annotate(points=Sum("votes__up") - Sum("votes__down")).values('points').order_by("-points")[:15]
```